# (Apparently) weird "Access denied" MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql

I just begun working on a legacy PHP application and found myself fighting a strange behavior. I'll try to explain the scenario/code/error:

1. All the queries are executed through a singleton class, which opens
   a connection and keeps it opened for the whole session (as far as I
   could understand the code)
2. Every time a `mysql_query` returns `false`, an exception is thrown.
3. MANY queries executes "fine", even complaining about not existing tables (one of my tasks is to clean up the messy-clipper-inherited-database-scheme, so I'm running the code and creating the tables as they are needed). After creating the missing tables, the queries usually runs well.
4. SOME queries are returning `1045` error: `Access denied for user 'appuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Here comes the "weird" behavior:

1. I have enabled the general log in my MySQL install, but there are just NO mentions of access denied errors. The application queries seem to run fine (I say "seem to" because I'm actually having problems understanding some sections of the log format).
2. The username/password configured in the singleton class is ok. I can log in using the MySQL CLI interface, besides MANY other queries runs fine. If I try to use a wrong username/password on MySQL CLI, the access denied is correctly logged in the general log.
3. The stack trace of the thrown exceptions (in PHP, obviously) shows that the exceptions really came from the singleton class that handle the queries.
4. There seems to be no pattern in the "rejected" queries. They are big `SELECT` queries, but nothing more. Some have `LEFT OUTER` joins, others have like 24 `FROM` clauses.
5. I'm logging the `mysql_stat` result, on every query, and it prints the server status before both working queries and the failing ones. Although, I'm not sure if this function actually depends on a valid credential/session with the MySQL server.

So, what do you guys think is going on down here? Any clue? Any educated guess?

If someone need more information/background, I'll happily provide... :)

Comment: Is there a possibility that these queries try to access a different database from the normal one in the join or from clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining in more details the problematic `SELECT`s, I could find a common table, between all them. Guess what? It was not a `TABLE`, but a `VIEW`, actually. When I tried to `SELECT` from this `VIEW`, using the graphic tool (MySQL Workbench), the error was clear and "obvious".

When the developer exported the database (MySQL Dump), the tool just added a line like this, on every `VIEW` creation code:

```
/*!50013 DEFINER=`oldappuser`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
```

I don't know why, but it did. Since my local database has a different username/password/scheme, this became the source of my 4-hours-long-headache.

To fix it I just dropped the old `VIEW` and re-created it, without the `DEFINER` directive.

Moral of the story: watch out for the options you check when dumping your database and pay attention to this `SECURITY` stuff, in case you are changing your user/pass/scheme in the new server.